# Angular 6 Observable chaining and error handling

Tags: observable, angular6

I am getting the param via observable and if it is of proper enum type then i fetch data. I am not using snapshot for getting the param. This needs to use observable.

Also, there is a refresh button on the page and it just calls the second data method directly since we'll have the correct enum available to fetch data for.

Currently the following works for me.

```
export class MaintainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  grouptType: zGroupTypes;
  title: string = "";
  isError: boolean = false;
  errorMessage: string = "";
  groupList: Group[];

  //handles to destroy the observables manually 
  activatedRouteSubscription: Subscription; 
  groupSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = "";
    this.isError = false;
    this.errorMessage = "";
    this.groupList = [];

    this.checkAndGetData();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.activatedRouteSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.groupSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onRefresh() {
    this.getGroupInfo();
  }

  checkAndGetData() {

    this.activatedRouteSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.grouptType = <zGroupTypes>params['type'];
        if (this.grouptType && this.grouptType in zGroupTypes) {
          //good
          this.title = zGroupTypes[this.grouptType];
          //get the group info
          this.getGroupInfo();
        }
        else {
          //error - redirect to resource missing
          this.router.navigate(['resource-missing']);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  getGroupInfo() {
    this.groupList = [];
    this.isError = false;
    this.errorMessage = "";

    const params = new HttpParams().set('groupType', this.grouptType.toString());
    this.groupSubscription = this.dataService.pull<Group[]>(`${this.dataService.endPointGroup}/GetGroupByAttributeId`, params).subscribe(
      res => {
        //res is of type Group[]
        if (!res || res.length <= 0) {
          this.isError = true;
          this.errorMessage = "No Data Found";
        }
        else {
          this.groupList = res;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.isError = true;
        this.errorMessage = "Error happened"; //console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

I want to rewrite this so that i don't use an observable inside an observable. After some reading, i have to use mergeMap but then how to

1. handle errors as being handled by both of my functions.
2. on refresh only pull the groupInfo since i don't need to get the groupId again. It will get populated the on page load.

I found an example online to do chaining which looks like

```
export class AppComponent {
  homeworld: Observable<{}>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.homeworld = this.http.get('/api/people/1').pipe(
      mergeMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld))
    );
  }
}
```

but then this doesn't show how to handle errors.

I started some thing like following but i am kind of lost since i am still relatively new to angular and operators are still not my strong point.

```
  getData() {
    let singleCall = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
      map(params => {
        this.grouptType = <zGroupTypes>params['type'];
      }),
      filter(() => this.grouptType && this.grouptType in zGroupTypes),
      mergeMap(() => {
        const paramToPass = new HttpParams().set('groupType', this.grouptType.toString());
        this.dataService.pull<Group[]>(`${this.dataService.endPointGroup}/GetGroupByAttributeId`, paramToPass)
        .... how to proceed here
      })
    );
  }
```

or is it safe to say that my original approach is still proper way of handling this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `map` function, you must return new value. Don't assign side-effect inside it. Moreover, in this case, you should use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`

```js
getData() {
  let singleCall = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    map(params => params.type),
    tap((groupType) => this.groupType = groupType),
    filter((groupType) => groupType && groupType in zGroupTypes),
    switchMap(() => {
      const paramToPass = new HttpParams().set('groupType', this.grouptType.toString());
      return this.dataService.pull<Group[]>(`${this.dataService.endPointGroup}/GetGroupByAttributeId`, paramToPass)
    })
  );
}
```

EDIT: If you want to switch case of `groupType`, you can extend to 2 `Observable`

```js
const param$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
  map(params => params.type),
  tap((groupType) => this.groupType = groupType),
);

param$.pipe(
  filter((groupType) => !(groupType && groupType in zGroupTypes)),
).subscribe(() => {
  console.error("Failed")
});

param$.pipe(
  filter((groupType) => groupType && groupType in zGroupTypes),
  switchMap(() => {
    const paramToPass = new HttpParams().set('groupType', this.grouptType.toString());
    return this.dataService.pull<Group[]>(`${this.dataService.endPointGroup}/GetGroupByAttributeId`, paramToPass)
  })
).subscribe((results) => {
 // to do
});
```

Comment: what is getData() returning, is it observable? So, if groupType isn't good then switchMap will not execute, am i correct? and i am going to handle error in the refresh and ngonInit, some thing like `this.getData.observable( res => {...}, error => {...});`

Comment: Yes, it is. However, if you want `getData` return Observable, run must replace `let singleCall =` to `return`. Moreover, the correct syntax is `this.getData.subscribe`, not `this.getData.observable`. You can subscribe after pipe too, no need to return getData as Observable

Comment: `this.grouptType` is undefined  inside switchMap. filter has groupType but it is not being assigned to this.groupType

Comment: If you want to set `this.groupType`, you can append `tap((groupType) => this.groupType = groupType)` after `map` (see my example)

Comment: One more question, if filter fails then the subscribe at the end of pipe will not execute. How to handle filter fail to redirect or show error?

Comment: Update new code for your answer. You can extend to 2 Observables from param Observable.

Comment: Thanks! in my scenario, should i use this function or my original code with 2 functions is good enough? I have a refresh button, which needs to call the get data function as well. I don't need to go through getting the parm again since it got populated on load.

Comment: I think the step of getting param don't affect much about performance. However, if you want to use cached `this. groupType` on refreshing, you can use expression like this: `const param$ = this. groupType ? of(this.groupType) : this.activatedRoute...`. `of` function will wrap the value into observable. The remain code is the same

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial (a course/book) about operators? I need to invest into these.